# How to display a formatted DateTime in Spring MVC 3.0?

Tags: formatting, spring-mvc

I have a Joda-DateTime field in my model and want to display it formatted in a JSP view. I have annotated it with the new @DateTimeFormat annotation:

```
public class Customer {
   private DateTime dateOfBirth;

   @DateTimeFormat(style="M-")
   public DateTime getDateOfBirth() {
      return dateOfBirth;
   }
}
```

Now I want to display the dateOfBirth in my JSP:

```
Date of birth: ${customer.dateOfBirth}
```

But the result is unformatted:

```
Date of birth: 2010-08-11T11:23:30.148+02:00
```

After some research I found out, that I have to use the spring:bind-tag:

```
<spring:bind path="customer.dateOfBirth">
   Date of birth: ${status.value}
</spring:bind>
```

With this it works. But it seems too complicated for this simple task. And using this method on lists is even more complicated since you have to integrate the list-index into the binding-path.

So my question is: Is there a simpler way to display a formatted value using the spring formatting-annotations?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `spring:eval` tag which understands the `@DateTimeFormat` rule:

```
<spring:eval expression="customer.dateOfBirth" />
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `@DateTimeFormat` rule from your model all-together and use Joda's formatDate tag as Naikus illustrates.

In a future release, Spring plans to support plugging in "SpEL", which is the "Spring Expression Language" invoked by spring:eval, as the default Unified EL implementation for your JSP pages.  This would allow in-line expressions like `${customer.dateOfBirth}` to be routed through SpEL as well.  You can vote up this enhancement request here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7459.

Comment: Spring:eval works great. Besides I upvoted the enhancement request for integrating SpEL in JSP. Thank you.

Comment: I found a small issue with spring:eval in version 3.0.3. When the expression evaluates to null, the string 'null' is printed. In contrast, the spring:bind example from my question prints an empty string when the expression evaluates to null. Is there a way to suppress the output of 'null'? Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Because its a joda datetime object, and not a Date object, you will have to write your own formatting function or a custom tag.

If you can convert it to java.util.Date somehow, then you can use the built in jstl's [fmt](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html) taglibrary.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${customer.dateOfBirth}" type="both" 
      pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />
```

But the latest jsp quickly allows you to create [custom](http://java.blogs.webucator.com/2010/05/09/creating-custom-jsp-tags/) [tags](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html).

Comment: the fmt link seems to be broken.

Comment: @noobMama you need to define taglib in jsp page: <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

Answer (score 0):

Spring gives us the option to set global date-time formats via the application properties file. Just add this config to application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd
spring.mvc.format.date-time=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss
```