# @DateTimeFormat not working properly

Tags: spring, datetime, format

I'm having issues with using the @DateTimeFormat Spring annotation.  I've been researching a bit about it today, but for some reason I just can't get it to work.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
@Column(name="my_date")
private Date myDate;

public Date getMyDate() {
    return this.myDate;
}
public void setMyDate(Date myDate) {
    this.myDate = myDate;
}
```

Right now the code is displaying the date and time as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S (i.e. 2012-01-11 00:00:00.0)

I read that you need Joda-Time added to your class path and I've done that.  Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457134/how-to-display-a-formatted-datetime-in-spring-mvc-3-0

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the processing of those annotations.  The easiest way is with [mvc schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)...

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Joda Time is not required for formatting. @DateTimeFormat can be used on long, Date and Calendar fields.  If you want to use it on Joda Time fields, you need to have 1.3 or higher on your classpath