# Formatting of BigDecimal in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bigdecimal

I have a bean with BigDecimal field defined as

```
@Digits(integer=3, fraction=2)
@NumberFormat(style=Style.NUMBER)
private BigDecimal vatRate = new BigDecimal(0.0f);
```

Formatting works well inside form (I use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`) but when trying to populate table with values as

```
<td> ${c.vatRate} %</td>
```

I am getting value as `12.30000000000000000000000000000000 %` or `0E-32 %`.

I have tried also to use `<fmt:formatNumber/>` but I got an exception

```
In &lt;formatNumber&gt;, value attribute can not be parsed into java.lang.Number: " 0E-32"
```

Right now it comes to me only solution with special String getter for my bean that will provide formatted value. But is there any "nice" solution in presentation layer (ideally honouring @Digits annotation?)

Comment: Did you try using "pattern" attribute in fmt:formatNumber (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm)

Comment: I have tried `<fmt:formatNumber value="${c.vatRate}" maxFractionDigits="2"/>` but as error suggests, there is a problem with parsing value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally I have found following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457134/how-to-display-a-formatted-datetime-in-spring-mvc-3-0) that solved my problem:

```
<td> <spring:eval expression="c.vatRate"/> %</td>
```