# spring mvc date format with form:input

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, jstl

I have hibernate entity and a bean:

```
@Entity
public class GeneralObservation {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Date date;

    @Column
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

also I have

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}
```

and

```
        form:input
                id = "datepicker"
                name="date"
                itemLabel="date"
                path="newObservation.date"
```

When I go to my url I see:

[image: my form]

How can I force it to have mm/DD/yyyy format? Thanx

Comment: `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")` and  `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")` both use `dd/MM/yyyy`. Have you tried to change them to `mm/DD/yyyy`?

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457134/how-to-display-a-formatted-datetime-in-spring-mvc-3-0

Comment: No, this wouldn't help, because form:input doesn't allow to put default value explicitly.

Comment: did you use [mvc:annotation-driven](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven)?

Comment: no, where should I put mvc:annotation-driven?

Comment: You should put it in the dispatcher servlet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to put
`<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
to 
mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
and also xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
to the begining of xml file.

Comment: what if I don't use xml for dispatcher ?

Answer (score 23):

You can use fmt:formatDate jstl tag:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${yourObject.date}" var="dateString" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
<form:input path="date" value="${dateString} .. />
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for misrepresentation. In my application I have same situation, but date format is correct (like I specify in DateTimeFormat annotation before field). And not only presentation of field is correct: I have no @InitBinder method and all works correct. Maybe I have newer version of spring library (3.1.1.RELEASE)?

Answer (score 5):

in my code I use the binder in this way:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Comment: Try:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   changeMonth : true,
   changeYear : true,
   dateFormat : 'dd/MM/yyyy'
  });
 });

<form:input path="datepicker" />

Comment: I don't need datepicker. Date format is not what I've expected.

Answer (score -2):

In HTML5 there is input type="date", same thing in Spring (Chrome , Opera, and I this Safary too, but not yet in Firefox

```
<form:input type="date" ... >
```

Comment: why is this in -ve ?