# how to bind date in spring field to pojo class

Tags: java, spring, jsp

1. I wanted to bind the spring date field to the pojo class and return the date
2. The dateOfbirth is of type java.sql.Date . Now when i pass the date from spring form to the function setDateOfBirth ,it is taking null value

For example in **register.jsp** (Registration form) I have the particular field

```
<form:label path="DateOfBirth">DateOfBirth</form:label>
<form:input path="DateOfBirth" type="date"/>
```

**Register.java** (Pojo class)

```
 public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
   this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth   ;
 }

 public void getDateOfBirth() {
   return this.dateOfBirth;
 }
```

when I call **getDateOfBirth()**
returns: `Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 IST 1992`

```
Input :- 12/12/1992
```

Expected `Output :-  12/12/1992`

What I get: `null`

Please help me how to convert this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring mvc date format with form:input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163404/spring-mvc-date-format-with-forminput)

Comment: you should be using a String rather than date in that case as for Date it should be date not some formatted Date. To get formatted date use SimpleDateFormat or jstl tags on views.

Comment: In the  link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163404/spring-mvc-date-format-with-forminput   Result is in format : Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 IST 1992 . But i want the result in 12/12/1992

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [`@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) to your `dateOfBirth` in `Register.java`

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

Comment: I wanted to insert sql date . so i defined  dateOfBirth in Register.java as java.sql.Date  . When i call getDateOfBirth() , it gives me null .